# How to shift a system of equations to the left

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, empheq

I need to shift a system of equations to the left; there is space so maybe there is a trick to do it. Could you suggest me a way to overcome the problem please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\eta &= \frac{\tau_{out} \, \omega}{V \, I}
\\
\tau_{out} &= \tau - \tau_{friction} = k_t \, I - k_t \, I_0 = k_t \, (I - I_0) = k_t \, I_a
&&\text{(a)} \\
\omega &= \frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R \, \tau}{k_t^2} =
\frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R \, I}{k_t} =
\frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) =
\frac{V}{k_t} \, \frac{R}{R} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) =
\frac{I_{stall}}{k_t} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) =
\frac{R}{k_t} (I_{stall} - I_0 - I_a)
&& \text{(b)} \\
V &= R \, I_{stall}
&& \text{(c)}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: unrelated but `\tau_{\mathrm{friction}}` never use  math italic for words, see your image above, that separates the letters as a product of one-letter variables, not a single multi-letter name.

Comment: you need additional `\\ ` to bring the = to the next line, it is too wide as it is

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle thank you for the useful suggestion about the mathrm. About the question, maybe I can force the system to shift to the left?

Comment: you could move it a bit but `Overfull \hbox (189.22818pt too wide) detected at line 30` it is _far_ too wide, it needs splitting over more lines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I followed your idea:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add two line breaks for the `\omega` equation (equation #3).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
%\usepackage{amsmath} % empheq loads amsmath automatically
\usepackage{empheq} 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\eta &= \frac{\tau_{\mathrm{out}}\,\omega}{V I} \\
\tau_{\mathrm{out}} &= \tau - \tau_{\mathrm{friction}} 
      = k_t I - k_t I_0 = k_t (I - I_0) = k_t I_a
  &&\text{(a)} \\
\omega &= \frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R \tau}{k_t^2} 
        = \frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R\,I}{k_t} 
        = \frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) \notag\\
       &= \frac{V}{k_t} \frac{R}{R} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) 
        = \frac{I_{\mathrm{stall}}}{k_t} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) \notag\\
       &= \frac{R}{k_t} (I_{\mathrm{stall}} - I_0 - I_a)
  && \text{(b)} \\
V &= R\,I_{\mathrm{stall}}
  && \text{(c)}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you either want the equation numbers or the tags (a), (b) and (c), not both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\eta &= \frac{\tau_{\mathrm{out}} \omega}{V I} \notag
\\
\tau_{\mathrm{out}} &= 
  \tau - \tau_{\mathrm{friction}} = k_t  I - k_t  I_0 = k_t (I - I_0) = k_t I_a
\tag{a} \\
&\hphantom{{}={}}\begin{aligned}
  \mathllap{\omega={}}&\frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R \tau}{k_t^2} 
  =\frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R I}{k_t} \\
  \mathllap{={}}&\frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) 
  =\frac{V}{k_t}  \frac{R}{R} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) \\
  \mathllap{={}}&\frac{I_{\mathrm{stall}}}{k_t} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a)
  =\frac{R}{k_t} (I_{\mathrm{stall}} - I_0 - I_a)
\end{aligned}
\tag{b} \\
V &= R I_{\mathrm{stall}}
\tag{c}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

A bit of trickery is needed to place the (b) tag at the center of the split middle equations.

[image]

Notes.

I removed all `\,` bits that aren't necessary and spoil the spacing.

The textual subscripts are input as `\mathrm{out}` and similar.

I'm not sure what would be the use of a double tag. Anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\eta &= \frac{\tau_{\mathrm{out}} \omega}{V I}
\\
\tau_{\mathrm{out}} &= 
  \tau - \tau_{\mathrm{friction}} = k_t  I - k_t  I_0 = k_t (I - I_0) = k_t I_a
&&\text{(a)} \\
&\hphantom{{}={}}\begin{aligned}
  \mathllap{\omega={}}&\frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R \tau}{k_t^2} 
  =\frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R I}{k_t} \\
  \mathllap{={}}&\frac{V}{k_t} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) 
  =\frac{V}{k_t}  \frac{R}{R} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a) \\
  \mathllap{={}}&\frac{I_{\mathrm{stall}}}{k_t} - \frac{R}{k_t} (I_0 + I_a)
  =\frac{R}{k_t} (I_{\mathrm{stall}} - I_0 - I_a)
\end{aligned}
&&\text{(b)} \\
V &= R I_{\mathrm{stall}}
&&\text{(c)}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @egreg thank you for the answer; I need both tags and numbers because I use the tags in a different way with respect to the numbers.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Not difficult to add both. I still can't understand.

Comment: Hello @egreg in practise I've many equations (es. eq. number 7.104) and under the system I explain the various steps of each equation. I add a letter only at the right of the equations that need explanation and it's more comfortable to use a single letter instead of a long number (es. 7.104). Btw thank you for the editing of your answer.